# problem retrieving selected lines google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm trying to retrive and loop through selected lines in a spreadsheet using google app script, I'm using the code below:

```
var ranges = activeSheet.getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
   //ranges.push(ranges[ranges.length-1]);
   ranges.forEach(function(range){
     if (range != [])
     range.getValues().forEach(function(row){
        // some
        // code
        // here
     })
  })
```

The code works fine except that in the result I get always one of the lines empty however  in the spreadsheet it is not

Comment: Can you provide more information? With the provided information, this behavior is not reproducible (the code inside the inner `forEach` as well as a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on might be useful).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
function main() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ranges = activeSheet.getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
   ranges.forEach(function(range){
     if (range != []) range.getValues().forEach(function(row){ Logger.log(row) })
  })
}
```

Here is my sheet (three cells are selected):

[image]

Here is an output:

[image]

Or, selected three lines:

[image]

Here is an output:

[image]

I see no problem. What do you mean?